# What is the difference between the Lie algebra of the orthogonal group and the spin group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, clifford-algebras

I'm going to restrict my question to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm reading that the Lie algebra of $O(n)$ is the algebra of bivectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm also reading that if you write the Clifford algebra
$$Cl(n)=Cl^0(n)\oplus Cl^1(n)\oplus Cl^2(n)\oplus ...$$
That the Lie algebra of $Spin(n)$ is $Cl^2$. But isn't $Cl^2$ the space of bivectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Or am I mixing it up with the exterior algebra? If $Spin(n)$ and $O(n)$ have the same Lie algebra, is there a difference in the exponential map?

Comment: The spin group being a double cover of the special orthogonal group, it has indeed the same Lie algebra (which is also the Lie algebra of the orthogonal group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spin group is a cover of the orthogonal group, therefore they have the same Lie algebra

Comment: Is that a theorem of lie algebra of covers that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @EbenCowley Indeed, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group) under the section "Lie groups".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the reference it helped a lot :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde There is one more thing though, the second part of my question still bugs me: if we write $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}=W\oplus \overline{W}$ then Spin(n) acts on W and therefore must have complex elements-unlike SO(n), so what is the difference between the exponential maps?